# pass string array from activity one to activity two, get values from string array and change layout accordingly

Tags: android, arrays, eclipse, string

where to start..
I'm new to android and trying to create a  small app for android that would show time table (5 days and 8 hours), those'd be displayed as a table of 40 squares. User can add an event by choosing Day(from spinner), Time(spinner), add a note (max 15 characters) and choose a background color. All that has to be added to a string array and send to main activity. From there by getting day and time slot values from that string array appropriate square will be updated with text and background color from the same string array. I've been trying to solve this for about four days now, but I just can't get my head round this... Here's some code:
Main Activity:

```
package com.tt;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button settings = (Button)findViewById(R.id.settings);

        Intent a = getIntent();
        String[] add = a.getStringArrayExtra("strings");

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView detail = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.m1);
        //detail.setText(notes);

        settings.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(),Settings.class);
                startActivityForResult(i,0);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Add event:

```
package com.tt;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;

public class Add extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnCheckedChangeListener {
    String[] DOW;
    String[] time;
    String  clr;
    EditText nts;
    boolean click = true;
    Button save;
    RadioGroup days;
    RadioGroup times;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add);
        initialize();

        DOW = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.DOW);
        Spinner s1 =(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<String>adapter = new      ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,DOW);
        s1.setAdapter(adapter);
        s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?>arg0,View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                int index = arg0.getSelectedItemPosition();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Chosen Day of the Week is     "+ DOW[index], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?>arg0){
                // nothing
            }
        });
        time = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.time);
        Spinner s2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,time);
        s2.setAdapter(adapter2);
        s2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?>arg0,View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                int index = arg0.getSelectedItemPosition();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Time is set to "+ time[index], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // nothing
            }
        });
    }
    private void initialize() {
        save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
        save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                String notes = nts.getText().toString();
                String day = DOW.toString();
                String tim = time.toString();
                //String color = clr.

                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                /*bag.putString("key1", day);
                //bag.putString("key2",tim);
                //bag.putString("key3", notes);
                //bag.putString("key4", color);*/

                /*String[] added = new String[4];
                added[0]=day;
                added[1]=tim;
                added[2]=color;
                added[3]=notes;*/

                //b.putStringArray("key",added);
                String[] added = new String[] {day, tim, notes};
                //b.putStringArray("key", new String[]{day, tim, notes});
                Intent a = new Intent(Add.this, MainActivity.class);
                a.putExtra("strings",added);
                startActivity(a);
            }
        });
        nts = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.notes);
        //days.setOnCheckedChangeListener((OnCheckedChangeListener) this);
        //times.setOnCheckedChangeListener((OnCheckedChangeListener) this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int arg1) {
        switch(arg1) {
        case R.id.blue:
            clr = "blue";
            break;
        case R.id.green:
            clr = "green";
            break;
        case R.id.yellow:
            clr = "yellow";
            break;
        case R.id.red:
            clr = "red";
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

***UPDATE***

Right... I've cut down string array to just one string... Here's the code that suppose to send data:

```
    private void initialize() 
{
    save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
    nts = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.notes);
}   
    public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            String notes = nts.getText().toString();
            //String day = DOW.toString();
            //String tim = time.toString();

            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("AddedNote", notes);
            Intent a = new Intent(Add.this, MainActivity.class);
            a.putExtras(b);
            startActivity(a);
            /*String[] added = new String[] {notes};
            a.putExtra("strings",added);
            */
        };
```

And the "receiver":

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
String gotNotes;
TextView notes;
   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initialize();
    Button settings = (Button)findViewById(R.id.settings);
    Bundle gotPackage = getIntent().getExtras();
    gotNotes = gotPackage.getString("AddedNote");
    if (gotNotes != "")
    {
    notes.setText(gotNotes);
    }
    else{}


    settings.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {



          public void onClick(View v)
         {
              Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(),Settings.class);
              startActivityForResult(i,0);
         }

    });

   }

    private void initialize() 
   {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    notes = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.m1);
}

@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
   {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;

    }

  }
```

The result I'm getting is caused by java.lang.nullpointerexception    at line :

```
   gotNotes = gotPackage.getString("AddedNote");
```

of the "receiver" activity..

Comment: And what is the exact problem you are facing? What is not working?

Comment: Well.... basically nothing is working..Before I was able to navigate to menu, add event page and remove event ..but now i can't even get to the menu

Comment: @Dims : app crashed or not if yes then post log with question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depend on your activity android:launchMode, I suspect you have it singleTask or similar. In this case you should override onNewIntent where you should receive the intent with your strings array.

Alternative solution, is to store data in a shared preference, you can serialize it as JSON object if needed.

```
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
   String[] add = a.getStringArrayExtra("strings");
}
```

Comment: Right... I've cut down string array to just one string... Here's the code that suppose to send data:

    private void initialize() 
 {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
  nts = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.notes);
 } 
  public void onClick(View arg0) 
   {
   String notes = nts.getText().toString();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("AddedNote", notes);
    Intent a = new Intent(Add.this, MainActivity.class);
    a.putExtras(b);
    startActivity(a);
    
    a.putExtra("strings",added);
    */
   };

Comment: oh no... thats a mess.. How can I add a long comment with the code again?

Comment: I've updated original question.. I couldn't find alternative way to post the code... Sorry about that mess....

Comment: Since you have singleTask, in the receiver class you need to copy the code from onCreate to onNewIntent as shown in my answer.

Comment: Sorry i don't really understand what i'll achieve by doing that...I'm a complete newbie..:)

Comment: When you have singleTask activity, onCreate will be called the first time the activity starts, but when you try to start it again and it is already running the the background onNewIntent will be called.